# Switch User within .bat File

Tags: powershell, batch-file, authentication, account

I've got a login script in which i need to map several network drives using a different, more priviledged user. For security purposes i don't put in my password on the script and let it prompt me once i login, however i need to type my password for each of the drives and it becomes too much.

say something like this

NET USE X: DRIVE /user:user *

repeated over 10 times, for different drives

Is there a way to push my credentials for all of the network drive mapping? or switch users within the same login script?

note: runas *other user* sample.bat does not work in this case, i need for it to switch while running the script

any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There's this thing called the clipboard, if you save a string to it, and use the paste function, you don't need to use repetitive typing. However, if your time is so precious, that you cannot, type your name ten times, I don't want to waste any more of it on providing comments, which don't directly answer your off topic question. This site helps you to fix a specific issue with your code. You haven't provided problematic code, you're simply looking for general programming advice, please try [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead for that.

Comment: I get that, and apologize, i was given responsibilities at work and i'm trying to automate as much as possible, i require to login at several computers multiple times throughout a day so i'm trying to be able to login and have everything ready, get me?

the question is simple, can i somehow prompt for credentials during a batch script, and use those crdentials to run the rest of the commands? I've tried google bu cannot find a solution other than "runas script.bat" which doesnt apply here, since this is a login script

Comment: Would it be okay, for your batch file to prompt you for the password, `Set /P "MyPwd=Please provide your password for this session>"`, then use `%MyPwd%` where necessary. Variables set like this are only local to the cmd.exe session, not globally to the system, when the script ends the password variable is discarded.

Comment: I believe the above can work, i tested it on command line and it seems reasonable, i will attempt it in play in a bit